# JsTree How to load_all node on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am implement Jstee in my project , 
When the tree loade ,  i am invoke the function **load_all**
that load all tha node in the beginning  and not when clicking on button , 
i want to create button that refresh the tree again !!
 **and "load_all" again in refresh!!**

```
 tree.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) 
 {
      tree.jstree("load_all");
 });

 $( "#refreshTree" ).on( "click", function(event)
  {
          event.preventDefault();
          tree.trigger("loaded.jstree");
          tree.jstree("refresh");
  });
```

this code is not success , it is just refresh my node but not load all node again !!

Comment: Did you try refresh? 
http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=refresh()

Comment: tree.jstree(true).refresh(); it refresh the tree but not Load all tree as i expected , the loading done when i am open the node by clicking on button  ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a binding to `refresh.jstree` that will trigger `load_all` on the tree.

```
 tree.bind("refresh.jstree", function (event, data) 
 {
     tree.jstree("load_all");
 });
```

and my click handler looks like:

```
 $( "#refreshTree" ).on( "click", function(event)
 {
    event.preventDefault();
    tree.jstree("refresh");  
 });
```